# Как правильно мокать статические классы в Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

Задача: есть какой-либо метод класса, который нужно протестировать. В нем используется статический метод другого кастомного класса. Как замокать этот статический класс?

```
Class testClass{
    public function testMethod(){
        $data = StaticClass::staticMethod();
  }
}
```

Есть вариант в сервис провайдере, который отвечает за бинд статического класса, проверять среду разработки, и если она тестовая - то биндить мок. Но не нравится этот вариант, так как подмешиваем код тестов в провайдеры. Или это норм?

Comment: Собственно поэтому и не рекомендуется юзать статические классы - их никак не подмокать в тестах(

Comment: @u_mulder Спасибо за ответ, печально :(

Comment: https://github.com/Codeception/AspectMock

Comment: @EugeneNagornichyh Спасибо, попробовал, но что-то не получается. Возможно сам Аспект не завелся правильно. Заводил на чистом проекте, была ошибка " Call to a member function registerClass() " Поэтому такая лапша в тесте:
https://pastebin.com/afrMYz9K